# What is limit is exceeded when I got this error: "Limit Exceeded: DriveApp."?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

Are there limits on a number of files/folder in Drive or access count through DriveApp? 
I just did not find answers to that and that error got thrown more and more often inside my scripts.

Comment: check the error code.   Limit Exceeded isn't the full message

Answer (score 5):

You can make a limited number of calls to the DriveApp service during a day. If the Google Script exceeds the quota, this error may occur though Google will automatically reset your quota the next day.

Unfortunately, the official documentation makes no mention about the number of calls you are allowed make before exceeding the limit. The same is true for other services like GmailApp.

Comment: That is what I expected but I just want to now the exact number so I can now how to react.

Answer (score -2):

All Google Apps Script quotas are available : [GAS Quotas](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas).

Regards

Comment: While a link is great, please [provide context to your link(s)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259/169503), as an *answer* should actually contain an answer. Be aware that being *barely more than a link to an external site* is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).